# Ethernet IPv4 problem on 20.04 on Dell Optiplex 780

Tags: networking

I am trying to set up a static IP address on the Intel-100 ethernet port using the gnome graphical method. I changed and applied it but the IP address change is not reflected when I go back to the details tab. The graphical screen says the Intel Ethernet is connected. When I try to ping the target, it fails. I've tried this on a different computer and everything works. On that computer, the details screen does show the IP address I had entered on the IPv4 screen. I've even disabled the IPv6 method. Is this an Ubuntu problem or a hardware problem?

Comment: "try to ping the target"? Details needed. Look at `ip route show`.Read https://askubuntu.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: The IP of the server is 192.168.1.3. My ping command from terminal is "ping 192.168.1.3" and on computer number 2, there are correct returns. On the problem computer, it returns "Destination Unreachable." BTW, it's unclear to me why you think I should read about how to ask questions.